# Log JBoss Logins

Tags: logging, authentication, jboss

Is there a way to log JBoss Form Based logins?
I want to create a statistic of people that login to my web application, but so far I was not able to add a function or procedure to the JBoss login action.

**Edit:**
I am currently using JBoss 5.1, if possible I would like to keep the current login process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of which version of jboss you're using, so this is for 5.x.

You could write a `login-module` which did logging for you, so you'd have login-config.xml somewhat like this:

```
 <application-policy name="my-policy">
<authentication>
    <login-module code="org.whatever.MyLoginModule" flag="required" />
</authentication>
</application-policy>
```

See [here](http://goo.gl/hvpDi) and [here](http://goo.gl/C2cMo) for more info on how to write a loginmodule.

Answer (score 0):

The access log file should contain the username of authenticated user.